# how to use conditional validation in jquery validater plugin to my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

when i select a type from a drop down box the form fields are changing . 
changing means hiding or showing , so according to the drop-down value the form fields are hiding and showing , i need to add j query validation plugin to this form  ,

i have a input

```
<div class="form-item">
                                                        <div class="catergory-inputs">
                                                            <input name="address" type="text" class="textarea_medium"
                                                                id="Address" value="<?php echo $address['value'] ; ?>" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

i validate this

```
 var x=$("#contactinfo").validate({
            rules: {

                address: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    lettersonly: true                   
               },
 },

            messages: {

                address: {
                    required: "Enter your Address",
                    minlength: "At least 3 characters long"
                },
            }
        });
```

i want to validate this field if only this field is not hiding . like this

```
 var x=$("#contactinfo").validate({
            rules: {
                if(not hiding) {
                address: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    lettersonly: true
                   } 
               },
 },

            messages: {
                if(not hiding) {
                address: {
                    required: "Enter your Address",
                    minlength: "At least 3 characters long"
                  } 
                },
            }
        });
```

how can i do this , i saw similar questions in stack-overflow  .but there were no answer to mh question there , plz help me ............................. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to conditionally validate a username field to make sure it was not in the database but only on creating a new user. So when creating a new I placed a javascript variable `var newUser=true;` else editing existing user `var newUser=false;`

Then in my rules portion of my validate I put `required: (newUser)?true:false`

This causes validate to validate the username field only if new user is `true`. If we loaded up an existing user, then the `required` portion of the rule will have the value `false` simply by adding the javascript var in your PHP code.

Remember, you can put javascript into a json object.  Because it's all javascript!

These are the resources I used in learning about validate: http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//articles/DOMM-7LZJN7 //article detailing how to really use validate. http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//pages/jQuery%20validation%20code
http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

There is also an amazing depth of information simply in http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation ...you just gotta click through it all!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the visible selector.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

this is untested but;

```
var x=$("#contactinfo:visible").validate({
```

By the way, when using the validation plugin you can do this;

```
<input type=text class="required" id="txtName"/>
```

then when you call the validate() method, if the textbox is hidden it will not be validated.  The trick is to add the "required" class to the class attribute